# Simple Javascript button 2 in 1

Tags: javascript, button

Hi im just having some issues,
Im trying to make this text blink with just one button click

So Click ON
And also Click Acts as OFF ( If clicks value is set to on which is 1 )

Im pretty new to JS any help would be appreciated

```js
  var Blinker = {
    interval: null,
    start: function() {
        if (this.interval) return;
        this.interval = setInterval(function() {       
            $('#demo').toggle();
        }, 250);
    },
    stop: function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        $('#demo').show();
        this.interval = null;
    }
}

//Initialize blink status.
var blinkStatus = 1;

//Check if status is changed, and run/stop blinking. 
setInterval(function() {
    if (blinkStatus == 1) {
        Blinker.start();
    }
    else {
        Blinker.stop();
    }
}, 250);


$('#start').on('click', function() {
    blinkStatus = 1;
});
$('#stop').on('click', function() {
    blinkStatus = 0;
});
```

```html
<h1 id="demo">PAUSE</h1>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Could the problem be somewhere around `    if (blinkStatus == 1) {
        Blinker.stop();
    }
    else {
        Blinker.stop();
    }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. This toggles blinking with a single button.

HTML:

```
<div class="text-container">
   <h1 id="demo">PAUSE</h1>
</div>
<button id="toggle-button">Start</button>
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.text-container {
  height: 17px;
}
```

JS:

```
var Blinker = {
    interval: null,
    start: function() {
        if (this.interval) return;
        this.interval = setInterval(function() {
            $('#demo').toggleClass('hide');
        }, 250);
    },
    stop: function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        $('#demo').removeClass('hide');
        this.interval = null;
    }
}

//Initialize blink status.
var blinkStatus = 0;

//Check if status is changed, and run/stop blinking. 
setInterval(function() {
    if (blinkStatus == 1) {
        $('#toggle-button').text('Stop');
        Blinker.start();
    }
    else {
        $('#toggle-button').text('Start');
        Blinker.stop();
    }
}, 250);


$('#toggle-button').on('click', function() {
    if (blinkStatus) {
       blinkStatus = 0;
    } else {
       blinkStatus = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome @MitchellChelin :)

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your code slightly, basing on your request on the comment.

```js
//Initialize blink status.
var blinkStatus = false;

//Check if status is changed, and run/stop blinking. 
var blinker, visibility;
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    blinkStatus = !blinkStatus;
    if(blinkStatus){
        blinker = setInterval(function() {
            visibility = $("#demo").css('visibility');
            
            if(visibility == 'hidden'){
                $("#demo").css('visibility', 'visible');
            }else{
                $("#demo").css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }
        }, 500);
        $("#button").text('Stop');
    }else{
        clearInterval(blinker);
        $("#button").text('Start');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="demo">PAUSE</h1>
<button id="button">Start</button>
```

Comment: thanks, i made a mistake there, but my problem still remains,
how can i enable this now to act a single button

for both start and stop.

Comment: Oh, so you mean, with just 1 click => start/stop flexibily?

Comment: Yes if possible.